# Magento 1 remove Disallow: /tag/ in robot.txt

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, robots.txt

My robots.txt contain any code and this code
Disallow: /tag/
Is it okay for SEO to delete this command?

Answer (score 0):

On my mind think you remove this `Disallow: /tag/` not affect any code structure and magento 1 website.So i think it is good remove.

> ## Disallow: /tag/ # uncomment if you’re not using tags

How to remove : ---

In `# Paths (clean URLs)`

```
Disallow: /tag/
```

And most useful more information link :-

**https://inchoo.net/ecommerce/ultimate-magento-robots-txt-file-examples/**

Thanks...

Comment: In the link that you have introduced   
It should be written in the file   
What do you think I should do?

Comment: in my answer already add.write or not write but magento structure not change...

Comment: and my mind say you write